# Find who or what is asking for a permission at runtime

Tags: android, android-permissions, react-native

Now with dynamic permission requests on Android, it happens that one of the dependencies I'm using in my Android project is requesting for access to the user photo library as soon as the app launches.

I don't like that because the user is not being informed why that permission is requested, so I want to stop this.

Now I'm using many dependencies that might need that permission, some of them are typical dependencies:

`compile ('com.a.dependency')`

and others are sub-project dependencies:

`compile project(':another-dependency')`

How can I find out who's asking for that permission?

Thank you

Edit: My project is a `react-native` project - not sure if that matters though.

Comment: no library can run it's code on startup unless you made it to run it. Check what you initialize, use base classes from the library, or do something with.

Comment: The problem is I have a dozen libraries, some of which I updated recently, and in order to find which one is doing that it's going to be like searching for a needle in haystack.

I'm looking of a more elegant way to tackle this.

Comment: I don't think that you have to search really for a needle in haystack. You only need to check which libraries are initialized on your app startup. totally not all of them are.

Comment: or one more way is to set a breakpoint in the Android sources in place like `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`, and check the callstack

Comment: My project is a `react-native` project. That means there are a lot of things initialised during startup, some of the sub-projects are react-native modules, and so things get more complicated as to what get's initialised when.

Your `requestPermissions` suggestion is probably what I'm looking for, I'll test.

Comment: `react-native` that's what you should have mentioned in the question as well as in the question tags

Comment: I skipped mentioning it because I think that's an android thing. Ok so I'll edit my question.